# Logins from WP users table use on another page

Tags: database, users, login

I'm creating new website and I want use logins from WP table wp_users. I have problem with password encryption.
I tried something with PasswordHash(8, True) but it generated string, which doesn't match with db.
I'm using WP 4.3.1.

Can someone help me please ?
Thank you for all reply :)

Comment: Do you want to import users from one WordPress install to another?